# How to set two separate parts of a single line with different html codes?

Tags: html, css, button, box, text-align

I gone through w3schools.com, searched here, and tried several searches on the web.
I can't figure this out.
I have a div box set with style text.
But I like on the same line to overwrite one align text for a button that ends after text.
So that within the box the text aligns left and the button aligns right without interfering with the next line of text that is again meant to align left within the box.
Further more each line of text has it own title pop up and the button suppose to have its own title pop up but keeps getting over written by the lines title pop up.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="color:orange; border-style: solid; height: 500px; width: 20%; margin: left; float: right">
  <p title="Available food in your area.">Food: <span id="food">Abundant</span>
    <span style="align-self: right"><title="Move to a new area.  Be careful, it costs growth to move."><button type="button" style="color:green" onclick="move()"><b>Move!</b></button></span></p>
  <p title="This is your cells membrane type.">Membrane: <span id="membrane">Bubble</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The div box with css code.

```
<div style="color:orange; border-style: hidden; height: 500px; width: 20%; margin: left; float: right">
```

This is the first line of text.  It is working properly and properly aligns left within the box.  It has javascript code connected but that code is not the issue so I am not adding it.

```
<p title="Available food in your area.">Food: <span id="food">Abundant</span>
```

This is a button.  It is related tot he first line of text (above). I wish it to be right of the line of text and to align right in the box.  Its title is being over written by the above line of code's title.

```
<span style="align-self: right"><title="Move to a new area.  Be careful, it costs growth to move."><button type="button" style="color:green" onclick="move()"><b>Move!</b></button></span></p>
```

This is the second line of text.  It properly aligns left and its title is working properly.

```
<p title="This is your cells membrane type.">Membrane: <span id="membrane">Bubble</span></p>
```

I got the Run code snippet to work and showed the box.
Click full screen to see how it is all properly suppose to look.
Except the button is suppose to be on the right side of the box.

Comment: could you send us a small mockup?

Comment: How it should looks like. To be honest I don't get it...

Comment: Altered original post to try and be more clear.

Comment: `<title>` is not a valid element in `<body>`. Use `<em>`, `<strong>`, or `<b>` if you need it to stand out for emphasis.

Comment: `align-self` only applies to flex-items (i.e. children of a flex container(i.e. an element that has `display:flex` and `align-items`))

Comment: <title> is a valid element and adds pop up text when you hover over the labeled element.  Try it out by using run code and hovering your mouse cursor over the text.

Comment: That would explain why align-self didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>help</title>
<style>
    .dowhatnowparent {
        color: orange;
        border-style: hidden;
        height: 500px;
        width: 20%;
        float: right;
    }

    .dowhatnowchild {
        color: orange;
        border-style: hidden;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dowhatnowparent">
<div class="dowhatnowchild">
<span id="food" title="Available food in your area.">Food: Abundant</span>
<div style="float: right;">
<button type="button" style="color: green" onclick="move()" title="Move to a new area.  Be careful, it costs growth to move."><b>Move!</b></button>
</div>
<div class="dowhatnowchild">
<span title="This is your cells membrane type." id="membrane">Membrane: Bubble</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>function move() { alert('ok'); };</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I was a little confused on what you were asking for, but I tried.